# How to install BIND 9.5 in windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, bind

Please tell me the procedure to install BIND 9.5 in Windows Server 2003. If u can please provide me a link that can help me with this installation.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't want to run Windows DNS services? IMHO you should run the services that are built for the system so on Windows you run Windows DNS, on *nix run bind or any of the other multitude of decent DNS servers.

Ok, off the soapbox.

To actually answer you question, first you would [download bind here](http://oldwww.isc.org/sw/bind/view/?release=9.7.0rc1&noframes=1) after that the quick and dirty explanation is to "run Bindinstall.exe" also there is a good deal of documentation included, if you open the 'index.html' file, there is a link to something called "Readme1st" ... read it it explains everything you need to know to get a basic system up. the rest of the docs will tell you how to setup a zone file, and any options you would want to setup.

If you have problems with your zone file, come on back an ask us (hopefully more specific) questions about the issues you are having.